# Angular 6 Libraries as an alternative to npm packages

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli-v6, angular-library

I'm trying to find the best way share angular code (which contain modules, services, components, etc) among a variety of angular applications (some existing, some new).  I guess the standard solution is to publish this shared code as npm packages, but for a bunch of reasons, this is not possible.  Angular 6 libraries seem like a candidate for my use case, but I'm not sure about:

- Can I create angular workspaces just for a collection of libraries (i.e. no applications)?
- Can I reference the libraries in one workspace from another workspace (i.e. the one containing my application)?

Answer (score 3):

Answer for both questions is YES. Here is more details how to do it using git

1. Create separate git repository for your library, and link it to `src/commons` (as example) folder in your project by [GIT SUBMODULES](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
2. When you link your library git repository as submodule of your project you can make commit/push changes of your library directly from project (if you use SourceTree this is very easy). This means that you can update your library directly from project but You need to remember to not create dependencies outside your `src/commons`.

Comment: @erin The answer for both question is "YES". But I also add information about practical way how to achieve this goal using GIT. I update my answer to be more clear

Comment: nice article describing @KamilKiełczewski idea: https://dev.to/radw2020/components-library-with-angular-2c4a

Answer (score -2):

This is a great article that walks through not only creating a library but also how to package it and then import it into another Angular project.
https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-part-2-6e2bc1e14121